# table modification

Tags: sql, transformation

if i have such a table:

```
name attribute
john hat
john glasses
john jacket
Lisa hat
Lisa boots
```

what query can i use to get:

```
name attribute1 attribute2 attribute3
John hat         glasses   jacket
Lisa hat         boots     NULL
```

Comment: google `pivot query with the relevant database engine.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create local temporary table tmp_nr(NName varchar(50), maxnumber int) on commit preserve rows;
insert into tmp_nr
select Nname, count(*) as number
from T
group by Nname;
```

A temporary table to store the number of attributes

```
select Nname,attributte,attributte2,attributte3 from
(
select Nname,
attributte,
lag(attributte,1) over(partition by Nname order by Nname) as attributte2,
lag(attributte,2) over(partition by Nname order by Nname) as attributte3,
row_number() over(partition by Nname order by Nname) as number
from T
)x inner join tmp_nr on x.Nname=tmp_nr.Nname
where x.number = tmp_nr.maxnumber
```

The purpose of the join is to select only the rows with all items per person.

Comment: ok, but if there is 32 atributes per person as max, i don't think that you should create 32 columns. there should be another way

Comment: maybe you can store them in one column using a concatenate function

Comment: ok. the aproach is right i think. the result was not in the way i wanted it. but changed it miself TY.

Answer (score -2):

**ALTER TABLE** table_name
**ADD** column_name datatype

Add as much as column as you wish to by this syntax following this convention

For example:

ALTER TABLE supplier
  ADD supplier_name VARCHAR(50);